# How can we select a different message.xlf file in angular with a dropdown?

Tags: html, angular

I need to code a method or a function in Angular in order to chose with a dropdown which language I want to display. 
But I coded the dropdown and I do not know how can I code the link between the dropdown and the message.fr.xlf file and to display the content on the screen after. Can you help me please, I am stuck on this for 3 days....? 
My app.component.ts file is >

```
import { Component, LOCALE_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  minutes = 0;
  gender = 'female';
  fly = true;
  logo = 'https://angular.io/assets/images/logos/angular/angular.png';
  heroes: string[] = ['Magneta', 'Celeritas', 'Dynama'];
  public items: Array<string>;

  inc(i: number) {
    this.minutes = Math.min(5, Math.max(0, this.minutes + i));
  }
  male() { this.gender = 'male'; }
  female() { this.gender = 'female'; }
  other() { this.gender = 'other'; }

  myFuncEnglish(lang) {
    if (lang === 'EN') {
      console.log('function called is english');
    } else {
      console.log('function called is french');
    }
  }



}
```

and my HTML file is :

```
<h1 i18n="User welcome|An introduction header for this sample@@introductionHeader">
  Hello i18n!
</h1>

<ng-container i18n>I don't output any element</ng-container>

<br />

<img [src]="logo" i18n-title title="Angular logo" />
<br>
<button (click)="inc(1)">+</button> <button (click)="inc(-1)">-</button>
<span i18n>Updated {minutes, plural, =0 {just now} =1 {one minute ago} other {{{minutes}} minutes ago}}</span>
({{minutes}})
<br><br>
<button (click)="male()">&#9794;</button> <button (click)="female()">&#9792;</button> <button (click)="other()">&#9895;</button>
<span i18n>The author is {gender, select, male {male} female {female} other {other}}</span>
<br><br>
<span i18n>Updated: {minutes, plural,
  =0 {just now}
  =1 {one minute ago}
  other {{{minutes}} minutes ago by {gender, select, male {male} female {female} other {other}}}}
</span>


<select (ngModelChange)="myFuncEnglish($event)"  [(ngModel)]="lang">
  <option value="EN">English</option>
  <option value="FR">France</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. "how can I code the link between the dropdown and the message.fr.xlf" explain this. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am sorry I will try  to explain you better. So with the i18n angular translation method you can change the language you want to display on the screen with a command on the terminal, but I want to change it directly on the screen so to code directly the way to change the language inside the code.. @MaihanNijat

Comment: Read comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484154/angular-i18-internationalization-language-change-programmatically

Comment: And keep track of the feature here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16477

Comment: So I read the different link you sent me. And do you think It still right ? If i need to languages I need to built twice ? And do you know an other way to translate please ? @MaihanNijat